# Print the results of a python file in bash on several lines

Tags: python-3.x, bash, coffeescript

I have a python file that has a for loop.

Say the file `python.py`:

```
for i in "Hello"
    print(i, '\n')
```

I am running this code as a bash command in a `.coffee` file

```
    command: "export LANG=en_CA.UTF-8; python3 folder/python.py"

    refreshFrequency: 1000*60

    style: """
      top: 245px
      right: 0px
      width: 240px
      height: 600px
      margin-left: -(@width / 2)
      overflow: hidden
      .content
        background: rgba(#fff, 0.5)
        color: #152033
        margin-left: 3px
        font-size: 18px
        font-family: Ubuntu
        text-align: left
      .title
        background: rgba(#fff, 0.5)
        color: #152033
        font-size: 40px
        font-family: Ubuntu
        text-align: center
      bg-blur = 10px
      .bg-slice
        position: absolute
        top: -(bg-blur)
        left: -(bg-blur)
        width: 100% + 2*bg-blur
        height: 100% + 2*bg-blur
        -webkit-filter: blur(bg-blur)
    """

    render: (output) -> """
      <canvas class='bg-slice'></canvas>
      <div class='title'>Inbox:</div>
      <div class='content'>#{output}</div>
    """
```

The code then outputs `Hello` on a single line.
How do I get this code to output someting like this?

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

I did put `'\n'` inside of my print command in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your python code, there are no colons **:** after the for loop. Also there is no need to write "\n" with each line, python will automatically move each letter to new line:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
for i in "Hello":
    print(i)
```

Put this in your python script and the again compile your coffee script, it gives output as:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```